# Why the green inside newer turbofan engine nacelles?

Tags: jet-engine, turbojet

[image: picture of engine nacelle]What is the purpose of the recent phenomenon of green being seen inside newer turbofan engine nacelles, just to the front of the fan blades?

Comment: Because it's better than black-- that wouldn't contrast with the fan blades, and you'd have less light bouncing around in there during visual inspections.

Answer (score 9):

The green part of the fan case is an [acoustic liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_liner), used to dampen the engine noise. The liner is used both in the **fan case** and on the internal walls of the **engine nacelle**, but this particular segment is a part of the fan case. (please note that the fan case is an integral part of the engine, and is seperate from the nacelle).

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image]

Why is it painted green? It doesn't appear to be that way for any functional reason, just like there is no functional reason for the cyan colour of the [Ultrafan](https://images.app.goo.gl/aTCP1fpkntXyjQR19) blades; it's only a matter of looks.

In fact, it doesn't have to be painted green. On CFM56 for instance, the acoustic liner is painted white.
[image: Image 3]

On [GEnx](https://images.app.goo.gl/RHRi54q3WMCiCA7D8), it is painted black, while on [Trent XWB](https://images.app.goo.gl/yf1165XPqTM5op2a6) it is painted brown/red. So there is no fixed colour of choice for the acoustic liner.

<sub>**Sources:** PW1100: [Fan case diagram](https://lt.linkedin.com/posts/ana-rey-2b7b8b25_those-who-have-seen-pw1100-engines-would-activity-7020322145146671104-vzd-), [Engine image](https://images.app.goo.gl/h7jzKw5FsaV2qLSs9), [Engine-on-wing image](https://images.app.goo.gl/f6Qy2bDHtkaWikm26), [Acoustic liner detail](https://twitter.com/chainsawrocks/status/1539113017409179649) ; CFM56: [Acoustic panel image](https://slideplayer.com/slide/4405934/14/images/14/CFM56+Acoustic+Panels+Approved+Repairs+on+Fwd%2C+Mid%2C+and+Aft+Panels.jpg).</sub>

Comment: I suspect modern liners are **dyed**, not **painted**. Paint would compromise its function.