# Hexagonal Texture on RB211 Turbofan Intake

Tags: aerodynamics, turbofan, surface

I was at the science museum in London, and was looking at the Rolls Royce RB 211-22B. This particular engine was, I believe, the sixth one ever produced. The surface texture of the fan inlet looks like a half-complete honeycomb, composed of grey and black dots. Does anyone know what the function of these dots are, and, why they seems to be arranged in this semi-random hexagonal structure? My guess is something to do with thickening the boundary layer before it hits the fan tips, but I am especially curious as to why they chose such a specific structure.
[image: Rolls Royce RB 211-22B inlet]

Comment: Probably an acoustic liner, as explained [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/97770/7532).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an acoustic liner.  The holes on the surface are on a regular grid.  Underneath, there is a honeycomb layer.  That honeycomb is also uniform in size.  The alignment / misalignment of the holes and the honeycomb give rise to the semi-random looking pattern.

Comment: Thank you - you're right! I wonder if the misalignment between the holes and the honeycomb is deliberate (as opposed to each hole being in the centre of a honeycomb). Perhaps the reason for the misalignment is so that multiple acoustic harmonics can be dampened?

Comment: I know vanishingly little about acoustic liners.  I know that the size of the hole and the size of the volume behind the hole are very important parameters.  I have no idea about the effect of multiple holes vs. a single hole per chamber.

Comment: Maybe to avoid any resonation in the flow pattern?